# How to send a running process to jail?

Tags: process, chroot

[*"Go directly to jail; do not pass go, do not collect $200"* — Monopoly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_pass_go)

Is there any way to make a *running* process's all future file access behave as if it has always been in a `chroot` environment?

Comment: If the program has the `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability, it can make the `chroot()` syscall itself, making subsequent file accesses relative to the new root directory. Keep in mind though, that if the process holds open file descriptors to directories outside of the new root, it would be trivial for it to do directory traversal outside of the chroot, and unless it drops the `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability, change the root directory back to the actual file system root.

Comment: @ThomasNyman This sounds more like the process itself actively going to jail, but actually I want to _send_ it there externally. It's not really about sending a potentially harmful process into an unbreakable jail (I know `chroot` isn't suited for that) but rather about having a running helper script temporarily see a modified filesystem, as if some bind-mounts occurred, but without influencing the rest of the system

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this for a _running_ process in a straightforward manner. If the target OS is Linux, you could have the script [`unshare`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshare) a mount namespace, do the bind mounts there without them being visible outside the new mount namespace, but if you cannot modify the script, and the script is _already running_ I don't see how this can be done short of using the [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) interface to inject code into the running process to perform the `chroot()` or `unshare()`.

Comment: I have a feeling this question might be a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe it would be better to ask a question about what you _actually_ want to achieve with this.

Comment: @ThomasNyman It's more of a "Can I ..." question, though the related (though probably XY) application I had in mind is some kind of prisoner-exchange: I currently run Gentoo in a `chroot` environment on a NAS drive with custom host Linux. Ultimately, I'd like Gentoo to become the host system, but have the original firmware services run in a `chroot` environment such that their functionality (e.g. the non-standard power-switch management) remains available. So the chrooted Gentoo would put its host into a sub-chroot environment, effectively swapping prisoner and guard...

Comment: You might be able to pull off something like that using [`pivot_root`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root) in combination with [mount namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/) to at least make it appear as though the Gentoo chroot and host switch places, without actually affecting the host system. The [`pivot_root()` syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pivot_root) is typically used by the `initramfs` to change the root file system to the actual root during boot.

Comment: @ThomasNyman Thanks, I'll have a look at these!